# The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable. (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload, directory

I have two upload scripts that do very similar functions just with different directories.

```
function town_upload() {


        //Do not create a thumbnail
        $create_thumb = false;

        //Create the path for the upload
        $path = './public/uploads/towns/' . $this->uri->segment(3);

        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = $this->image_upload_overwrite;

        if ($this->input->post('image_type') == 'main_image') {
            $config['file_name'] = 'main.jpg';
            $create_thumb = true;
        } 

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_error', array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()));

        } else {

            //sucess so now we create the thumbnail
            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_success', $this->upload->data());
```

Example: If I had a town with the ID of 6, the upload directory would be public/uploads/towns/6. This works perfectly fine as the directory is created when the town is created. I have nearly the exact same function for hotels except the path is public/uploads/hotels/[ID]. I have set the permissions to 777 just to remove that from the equation for now.

I cannot figure this out as they are both very similar functions. Here is the hotel upload code:

```
 function hotel_upload() {

        //Create the path for the upload
        $path = './public/uploads/hotels/' . $this->uri->segment(3);

        chmod($path, 0777);

        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048'; //kilobytes (2048 = 2mb)
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

        if ($this->input->post('image_type') == 'main_image') {
            $config['file_name'] = 'main.jpg';
        }

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_error', array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors() . ' <br/>Path: ' . $path . '<br/>Image Type: ' . $this->input->post('image_type')));

        } else {

            //sucess so now we create the thumbnail
            $this->session->set_flashdata('upload_success', $this->upload->data());
```

The hotel function gives me the error "The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable.".

Here are the pages HTML forms:

TOWN:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/town_upload/' . $this->uri->segment(3));?>

            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

            <br /><br />

            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="image_type" checked="checked" class="radio" value="main_image" /> <label>Main Image</label>
                <input type="radio" name="image_type" class="radio" value="other_image" /> <label>Other Image</label>
            </p>

            <input type="submit" class="submit short" value="upload" />

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

HOTEL:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/hotel_upload/' . $this->uri->segment(3));?>

            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

            <br /><br />

            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="image_type" checked="checked" class="radio" value="main_image" /> <label>Main Image (shown when visitors search the website)</label>
                <input type="radio" name="image_type" class="radio" value="other_image" /> <label>Standard Image</label>
            </p>

            <input type="submit" class="submit short" value="upload" />

        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance! Been working on this for hours now.. :(

Comment: Is all that example code necessary to answer the question? I doubt so. Provide a *short* example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Does the target directory really exist? Where do you create it? Are both scripts in the same directory?

Comment: @cweiske That's all the code that is required as the hotel upload script as the do_upload method always returns false. With the HTML form I submit a simple image that meets all the requirements.

Comment: @Pekka both scripts are in the same controller, and the target directory does exist as I have checked many times with an FTP client. If it doesn't exist a different error shows up anyway.

Comment: @Sam can you try `is_writable()` on the directory?

Comment: @Pekka it returned true. I called this code [
       echo "writable:" . is_writable($path);
       exit(); ] and it returned "writable:1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just came back to this. I think permissions got messed up somewhere, I destroyed and recreated the folder and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesnt check the chmod works. For example, by default, apache loves to run as its own user or nobody, not you as a user. So, the chmod in your file may find the user its currently running as doesnt own the file, so the chmod fails.

First thing I would check would be the user PHP thinks it runs as, and the owner of the file.

There is the is_writable function, you could check the directory is writable.

Comment: I don't even need to chmod it as the directory is already 777, I have read about that but I don't understand why the town_upload function works and the hotel function doesn't as they are basically the same thing. 

Just checked if it is writeable and it returned true. Really don't know what's going on!

Comment: Can you do `echo $config["upload_path"];` after you set it so that we can see it's what you expect it to be

Comment: It returned "./public/uploads/hotels/7" and Filezilla says its there as well.

Comment: also check safe_mode command in php.ini file it should be in off mode.

Comment: Master value is off, but local is on? Why does the other function work then??

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem and found a possible reason for this behaviour. In my case, I had created the upload directory a while back. I upgraded php which put in a new php.ini file that had `safe_mod = On.` And now when I recreated the directory after erasing it, the new php parameters kicked in throwing this error message.

Could it just be possible that you created the town dir tree before a PHP upgrade and your hotel dir tree afterwards?