# The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable even with (seem to be) correct file permissions

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, file-permissions, centos7

I already looked into many similar question on this forum but none seem to solve my problem.

I will list at the bottom some of the question page I viewed on this forum, but let me lay my situation on this question first.

I am using codeigniter v 2.x
PHP 5.5.32
MariaDB 5.5.44
CentOS 7.2.1511

Below is the location of my application **vits**.

```
[root@VITSServer html]# pwd
/var/www/html
[root@VITSServer html]# ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x.  6 apache apache   92 Nov  9 17:55 .
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root   root     31 Nov 20  2015 ..
-rwxr--r--.  1 apache apache 1150 Oct 28  2015 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   20 Oct 12  2015 info.php
drwxrwxr-x. 11 apache apache 4096 Oct 27  2015 laravel5
drwxr-xr-x.  2 apache apache   22 Oct 14  2015 test
drwxrwxr-x.  7 apache apache 4096 Nov 10 11:16 vits
drwxr-xr-x.  3 apache apache   17 Nov  9 17:56 vits_v2.0
[root@VITSServer html]#
```

Next below is inside the vits directory

```
[root@VITSServer vits]# ll
total 1504
drwxrwxr-x. 15 apache apache    4096 Nov  9 17:27 application
drwxrwxr-x.  7 apache apache    4096 Nov  9 18:01 assets
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache apache    8192 Nov  9 18:08 files
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache apache    6452 Nov  9 17:50 index.php
drwxrwxr-x.  8 apache apache    4096 Nov  9 17:27 system
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 apache apache 1503295 Nov  9 17:27 vits_db.sql
```

my upload path is in the **"files"** directory. as seen above, I already set it to 777 and owner:group to apache. How ever my upload still returns an error stating ***"The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable"***.

I checked my php_info and it seems everything should have been ok.

[image]

The question now is, am I missing something here?

stackoverflow page I already viewed:

- [The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable. (Codeigniter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772544/the-upload-destination-folder-does-not-appear-to-be-writable-codeigniter)
- [Codeigniter Permission denied images upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056251/codeigniter-permission-denied-images-upload)
- [Uploading File Issue In Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321275/uploading-file-issue-in-codeigniter)
- and many other...

Comment: Is `files/` has sub directories?

Comment: there are 2, named thumbnails and data_export both has the ff permission and ownership --> drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache. But I only save the files inside the files/ directory and not to any of the sudirectories.

Comment: That's strange. Would you please check configs again in order to make sure the path is what you want? Or see what  `/var/log/apache/error.log` says?

Comment: I already did checking the path in the config fike. I echoed it on the page, I copied it and cd to it on my linux server, and as expected it is the right path. and nothing is in my apached error log :3

Comment: lol. What your config path goes like? Any syntax error? Watch `error.log` again while you are uploading  :/

Comment: I figured it out, Apparently my selinux is preventing it to be uploaded even with the correct permission and ownership. However, moving forward how can we make things work even with selinux enabled.. hmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127759/discussion-between-benyi-and-jcm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.

Apparently my selinux is **preventing** it to be uploaded even with the **correct permission and ownership**.

I disabled my selinux with the ff command:

```
setenforce 0
```

[UPDATE]

Alternatively, in order to retain your **selinux** status as **enabled**, we can change the context of our target upload directory.

There are 2 ways:

> 1. via [**chcon**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html) command. However, changes made with the chcon command do not survive a file system relabel, or the execution of the
>      restorecon command
> 2. via **[semanage fcontext](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html)**. Which is a persistent change.

Hope this would help others too.

Comment: Yes sir, but It seem I can not do it right away, it tells me I can have it check tomorrow. :)

Comment: Just call all with name.